# Whenever i start a new activity it comes in this theme , how to make it normal

Tags: android, android-activity

Sorry if its a bad question or what , i am a beginner , it was all normal before then i tried to add a toolbar now even if i delete the code or do anything this theme or whatever it is not changing.`

`

[image]

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jekpD.png)

Comment: just above the device there is a dropdown "NoActionBar"... you can choose the theme from there

Comment: change your theme to Apptheme

Comment: I changed it , but it hasnt become normal , Normally i had text colour as BLACK but now it has been changed to WHITE automatically , please help me out here

Comment: I have changed the theme but when i run the project in an emulator it shows the same theme as above.

Answer (score 0):

add toolbar:
res->styles->add a custom theme

```
   <style name="AppTheme.Mytheme">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   </style>
```

then in manifest

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Mytheme">
```

then in activity

```
toobar=findviewbyid(toolbarid);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```